# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : com/itextpdf/text/element

Tags: java, exception, runtime

When i am running an class file on browser through jsp page, In class file I am trying to make an a PDF. but i am getting the exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : com/itextpdf/text/element. I am using eclipse IDE and apache tomcat as server

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly an application packaging problem. Are you sure you have the itext jar file on your classpath?

Comment: Are you talking about the java build path in particular project?

Answer (score 1):

you should add jar in your classpath as DaveHowes said and in 'lib' folder under WEB-Inf

Comment: Are you talking about the java build path in particular project?

Comment: not only in java build path, it must be put  in two places first in java build path and in 'lib' folder wich is under Web-Inf

Comment: yes i have done both the things first put into Webinf/lib folder and then add to build path as external jar from the same folder i.e. lib

Comment: my jar file name is itextpdf-5.2.0

Comment: let the build path from the original folder an not from lib

Comment: tell me one thing please , do i need just this one jar? and can i have that path F:/itext

Comment: try to download the latest version it's called 5.5.0 and there is 9 JARs i think. And yes you can have that path

Comment: i have done all these points just now, it is giving the same error.